# Selecting a Good Dynamic Array Datatype in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, arrays

I have a database table of topics that changes frequently. Let's say the table has topic_id and topic in it.

In my code, I need to keep count of how many occurrences are used in each topic.

Whats a good dynamic array datatype to store the counts of each topic?

Should I use arrayList?

An example of how to use it would be helpful.

Comment: Do you need to do anything with the count(s) once you have it? Do you need to store the count somewhere, or are you just calculating it on the fly as needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary is probably a good choice, as pointed out by other answers.

Assumption:

- your topic_id is an `int` data type.

Usage example:

```
Dictionary<int, int> occurrencesOfTopicsByTopicID = new Dictionary<int, int>();

// The following code increments the number of occurrences of a specific topic,
// identified by a variable named "idOfTopic", by one.

int occurrences;

// Try to get the current count of occurrences for this topic.
// If this topic has not occurred previously,
// then there might not be an entry in the dictionary.
if (occurrencesOfTopicsByTopicID.TryGetValue(idOfTopic, out occurrences))
{
    // This topic already exists in the dictionary,
    // so just update the associated occurrence count by one
    occurrencesOfTopicsByTopicID[idOfTopic] = occurrences + 1;
}
else
{
    // This is the first occurrence of this topic,
    // so add a new entry to the dictionary with an occurrence count of one.
    occurrencesOfTopicsByTopicID.Add(idOfTopic, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `dictionary <int,int>`

Answer (score 1):

For anything where you have a key-value sort of data and need a collection of it, a Map (or Dictionary) is going to be the correct choice.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, int> topicCounts
```

or you can strongly type it a little more

```
Dictionary<Topic, int> topicCounts
```

then you just access the count like an indexer

Answer (score 1):

A good choice would be

```
Dictionary<int, int>
```

or if you're updating/reading it in multiple threads, the excellent

```
ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

Actually, if you like lambdas, ConcurrentDictionary has a (naturally thread safe) AddOrUpdate method that comes in handy when doing counts; can't think of a way to do this without multiple calls in the regular Dictionary<>.

```
var dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();

dictionary.AddOrUpdate(topic_id,          // For the topic with id topic_id
                       x => 1,            // Set count to 1 if it didn't already exist 
                       (x, y) => y + 1);  // Otherwise set to old value + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of `IDictionary<TKey, int>` where `TKey` matches the type you'll lookup on (perhaps `Topic` perhaps `int`).

The simplest and fastest for most uses is `Dictionary<int, int>`. However, since this is ASP.NET, and you seem to be using this for some sort of caching, you'll probably need to access this collection from multiple threads. `Dictionary` is safe for multiple concurrent readers, so if updates are infrequent then protecting it with a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is probably the way to go. If you could have multiple threads trying to update simultaneously though then you may get better preformance from `ConcurrentDictionary` or my own [`ThreadSafeDictionary`](http://hackcraft.github.com/Ariadne/documentation/html/T_Ariadne_Collections_ThreadSafeDictionary_2.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Yes . ArrayLists are the best.

Use this namespace to include ArrayLists

```
using System.Collections;
```

Declare an array list like

```
ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();
```

Add items to arraylist.

```
myArray.Add("Value");
```

Remove items from arraylist.

```
myArray.Remove("Value");
```

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725459/c-sharp-when-should-i-use-list-and-when-should-i-use-arraylist

Comment: why you think this is the best? I think it is not at all the right choice

Comment: ArrayList is not the best that's more of a personal opinion I would use a Dictionary<int, int>

Answer (score 0):

`List<System.Web.UI.Triplet>` can be used to store a list.

Triples has three properties (First, Second, Third) - which can hold TopicID, TopicName, Count.

Or you can create a custom class to hold your `Topic` information with `ID, Name, Count` properties.