# Vb.Net Array List and limits of ListItems

Tags: vb.net

I have declared an `ArrayList` like this

```
Dim List1 As ArrayList = New ArrayList
```

Adding a `ListItem` to it

```
Dim Item As String = ""
List1.Add(New ListItem(Item))
```

Is there is any limit how many characters the `ListItem` can contain?

Comment: Use a strongly typed `List(Of String)` instead of an `ArrayList`. _"Is there is any limit how many characters Item can contains."_ Your memory is the limit.

Comment: Not that I am aware.  Is this a functionality that you want to have?

Answer (score 2):

*"Is there is any limit how many characters Item can contains."* 
It's limited by the limit of the length of a `String` and your memory.

> The theoretical limit may be 2,147,483,647, but the practical limit is
>   nowhere near that. Since no single object in a .Net program may be
>   over 2GB and the string type uses unicode (2 bytes for each
>   character), the best you could do is 1,073,741,823, but you're not
>   likely to ever be able to allocate that on a 32-bit machine.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/140749/284240

Apart from that, always use a strongly typed [`List(Of ListItem)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx#Y0) instead of an `ArrayList`.

```
Dim List1 = New List(Of ListItem)
List1.Add(New ListItem("Foo1"))
```

[c# When should I use List and when should I use arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725459/c-sharp-when-should-i-use-list-and-when-should-i-use-arraylist)