# Insert to arraylist in specific position

Tags: c#

I am trying to insert a person's name into a specific position within my arraylist, i get an error when i run this:

```
public void InsertIntoArrayList(string actName, int posNum)
{
    snip
}
```

The user would enter the name into the name textbox then the position(index) at which to insert the string..
Any suggestions on an easier way to code this or a way i can change it?

The error i get is - that `the index is out of range`. i assume the conversion might be messed up?

Comment: show how you create ActorArrayList and the exact error message

Comment: Have you checked that the posNum is actually a number that you can insert to? Like within size of the ArrayList?

Comment: System.Collections.ArrayList ActorArrayList = new 
System.Collections.ArrayList();

The array list is filled with 5 names from a text file, then the user is able to add new names to it via the form and it will display in a combo box.

Comment: Are you asking a second, unrelated question with your last edit? Then clarify if your original question was answered(you can do that with the accept-button left beside an answer). Then ask another question.

Comment: yeah i had a second quick question, didnt know how to do it.. i just edited it in..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indices are zero based. So the first item is at index 0 and the tenth item at index 9. [`ArrayList.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.insert.aspx):

```
int posNum;
if(!int.TryParse(txtPosition.Text, out posNum))
{
    // show message
    return;
}
else if(posNum < 0 || posNum > ActorArrayList.Count)
{
    // show message
    return;
}
ActorArrayList.Insert(posNum, actName);
```

If you want to add the object at the end anyway, you just have to use [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add.aspx):

```
ActorArrayList.Add(actName);
```

Note: you should use a strongly typed `List<T>` instead of a `ArrayList`, they are redundant meanwhile. [c# When should I use List and when should I use arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725459/c-sharp-when-should-i-use-list-and-when-should-i-use-arraylist)

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the .ToList on your array then the List insert function.