# How can I serialize this xml array to a property in my class?

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, serialization, arraylist

```
[Serializable]
public class CampoAuxiliar
{
    private string descripcionAuxiliar;
    private DateTime fechaAuxiliar;
    private ArrayList opcion;

    public CampoAuxiliar() { }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "descripcionAuxiliar", Type = typeof(string))]
    public string DescripcionAuxiliar
    {
        get { return descripcionAuxiliar; }
        set { descripcionAuxiliar = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "fechaHabilitacion", Type = typeof(DateTime))]
    public DateTime FechaAuxiliar
    {
        get { return fechaAuxiliar; }
        set { fechaAuxiliar = value; }
    }

    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "opcion", Type = typeof(Opcion))]
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "AuxiliarA")]
    public ArrayList Opcion
    {
        get { return opcion; }
        set { opcion = value; }
    }
}
```

And this is my xml

```
- <auxiliarA>
  <descripcionAuxiliar>Campo A</descripcionAuxiliar> 
  <fechaHabilitacion>2017-04-19</fechaHabilitacion> 
+ <opcion>
  <codigoOpcion>01</codigoOpcion> 
  <descripcionOpcion>1</descripcionOpcion> 
  </opcion>
+ <opcion>
  <codigoOpcion>02</codigoOpcion> 
  <descripcionOpcion>2</descripcionOpcion> 
  </opcion>
+ <opcion>
  <codigoOpcion>03</codigoOpcion> 
  <descripcionOpcion>3</descripcionOpcion> 
  </opcion>
</auxiliarA>
```

My problem is I can't figure out how to serialize the "opcion" array into the ArrayList opcion of the class.
With this case it does work and assigns the other nodes properly except for the ArrayList one which returns me count = 0.

Comment: Have you tried simply decorating the Opcion property with [XmlElement(ElementName ="opcion")]? It worked for me.

Comment: OMG this worked! Thank you so much, I've been trying to solve it all day, trying everything but the obvious. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `CampoAuxiliar` class as follows:

```
[XmlRoot("auxiliarA")]
[XmlType("auxiliarA")]
public class CampoAuxiliar
{
    private string descripcionAuxiliar;
    private DateTime fechaAuxiliar;

    public CampoAuxiliar() { }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "descripcionAuxiliar", Type = typeof(string))]
    public string DescripcionAuxiliar
    {
        get { return descripcionAuxiliar; }
        set { descripcionAuxiliar = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "fechaHabilitacion", Type = typeof(DateTime))]
    public DateTime FechaAuxiliar
    {
        get { return fechaAuxiliar; }
        set { fechaAuxiliar = value; }
    }

    private ArrayList opcion;

    [XmlElement("opcion", Type = typeof(Opcion))]
    public ArrayList Opcion
    {
        get { return opcion; }
        set { opcion = value; }
    }
}
```

In addition, you *should* replace the `ArrayList` with a `List<Opcion>`:

```
    private List<Opcion> opcion;

    [XmlElement("opcion")]
    public List<Opcion> Opcion
    {
        get { return opcion; }
        set { opcion = value; }
    }
```

Notes:

- [`[XmlRoot("auxiliarA")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx) indicates that the root element name is `<auxiliarA>` not `<CampoAuxiliar>`.
- [`[XmlElement("opcion")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) indicates that the collection is to be serialized without an outer container element.
- See [ArrayList vs List<> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2309694/3744182) and [c# When should I use List and when should I use arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/725459/3744182) for some discussion of why to prefer `List<T>` over `ArrayList`.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aXZAQT).