# Html.DropDownListFor: NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following razor code:

```
<div class="value"> @Html.DropDownListFor(
                       model => model.physicalAtributtes.bloodGroup,
                       new SelectList(Model.physicalAtributtes.BloodGroups)
                    ) 
</div>
```

And I have the following Model:

```
public class Donor
{
    public PersonalData personalData { get; set; }
    public PhysicalAtributtes physicalAtributtes { get; set; }
}

public class PersonalData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string adress { get; set; }
    public DateTime birthDate { get; set; }
    public string bornCity { get; set; }
    public string citizenIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string nationality { get; set; }
    public string profession { get; set; }
    public string academicDegree { get; set; }
    public string maritalStatus { get; set; }
    public int sonsNumber { get; set; }
}

public class PhysicalAtributtes
{
    private ArrayList bloodGroups = new ArrayList { "A+", "A-", "AB+", "AB-", "B+", "B-", "O+", "O-" };

    public double height { get; set; }
    public double weight { get; set; }
    public string skinColor { get; set; }
    public string eyesColor { get; set; }
    public string hairColor { get; set; }
    public string hairTexture { get; set; }
    public string bloodGroup { get; set; }
    public string ethnicity { get; set; }
    public ArrayList BloodGroups { get => bloodGroups; set => bloodGroups = value; }
}
```

The IISExpress gives the following error and I'm not understanding why:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>   AspNetCore._Views_Donor_Register_cshtml+d__0.MoveNext()
>   in Register.cshtml, line 96

Anyone have a idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList`.

Comment: @SLaks I can change, but why i shouldn't use `ArrayList`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/725475/34397

Comment: Also, your model property doesn't make any sense; the list of blood types is neither writable nor part of any particular person.

Comment: I successfully populating `DropDownListFor` as in this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3IAyWV. Possibly `Model.physicalAtributtes.BloodGroups` causing the exception, can you provide what `@model` directive refers to (and related view code)?