# Search within a list of type class c#

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have a class which has an ID and a few columns, one of which is a string.

```
public class myData
    {
        public Int64 myID { get; set; }
        public string myTitle{ get; set; }
        public string myForename{ get; set; }
        public string mySurname{ get; set; }
    }
```

There are a few million rows in the list and I want to search for all rows that have a mySurname that contains a specific string

I started to look at Contains but a little stuck on syntax where searching within a class, all examples I can find are only searching in a simple list of type string.

Ideally I want to get the full rows that match, or if not then the ID will do fine

Comment: `list.Where(item => item.mySurname.Contains(specificString))`?

Comment: how did you get the millions of rows into the list to begin with?  It's likely there's better places to do the search than within a list that has millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have the following list:

```
List<myData> dta = new List<myData>()
{
    new myData()
    {
        myID = 1,
        mySurname = "tst"
    },
    new myData()
    {
        myID = 1,
        mySurname = "11test2"
    }
};
```

If you need to return in a list all the records that contain the word 'test' in the `mySurname` field, you can do it with 2 ways that are exactly the same:

1)

```
var res = dta.Where(d => d.mySurname.Contains("test")).ToList();
```

2. 

```
var res2 = (from d in dta
            where d.mySurname.Contains("test")
            select d).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ

```
List<myData> list = new List<myData>();
myData m = list.Find(s=>s.mySurname==specificString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned the `arraylist` tag, you can write a query like:

```
var data = new ArrayList();

data.Add(new myData { mySurname = "john 1" });
data.Add(new myData { mySurname = "john 2" });
data.Add(new myData { mySurname = "peter 1" });
data.Add(new myData { mySurname = "peter 2" });

var result = from myData item in data
             where item.mySurname.Contains("peter")
             select item;

foreach ( var item in result )
  Console.WriteLine(item.mySurname);
```

To have a `List<myData>` typed collection, you can also write:

```
var list = result.ToList()
```

Or if you need an ArrayList:

```
var dataFiltered = new ArrayList(result.ToArray());

foreach ( myData item in dataFiltered )
```

If you need to do a case insensitive search:

[Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

You should use a `List<myData>` instead of an `ArrayList` :

[c# When should I use List and when should I use arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725459/c-sharp-when-should-i-use-list-and-when-should-i-use-arraylist)

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist

**Output**

```
peter 1
peter 2
```